# Segmentation Fault at Do/while loop

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

I have a function to add a new contact and store it in a file, also it will be stored in a linked list. I have a do/while loop to check if the phone Number that user entered is already available but I'm having a segmentation fault at this loop

```
void addContact(contactPtr *sPtr)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    contactPtr checkPtr = *sPtr;
    contactPtr crntPtr=checkPtr;
    contactPtr prevPtr;
    contactPtr newPtr;
    int check = 0;

    newPtr = (Contact *)malloc(sizeof(Contact));
    printf("Enter contact name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(newPtr->name);

    do
    {
        checkPtr=crntPtr;
        check=0;
        printf("Enter contact number: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(newPtr->phoneNum);
        for (checkPtr; checkPtr != NULL; checkPtr = checkPtr->next)
        {
            if (strcmp(checkPtr->phoneNum, newPtr->phoneNum) == 0)
            {
                printf("Phone No is already available\n");
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (check);

    fprintf(fptr, "\n%s\n", newPtr->name);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", newPtr->phoneNum);

    checkPtr = crntPtr;
    while (checkPtr != NULL)
    {
        crntPtr = checkPtr;
        checkPtr = checkPtr->next;
    }
    while (crntPtr != NULL && (strcmp(newPtr->name, crntPtr->name) > 0))
    {
        prevPtr = crntPtr;
        crntPtr = crntPtr->next;
    }
    if (prevPtr == NULL)
    {
        newPtr->next = *sPtr;
        *sPtr = newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        prevPtr->next = newPtr;
        newPtr->next = crntPtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you run your code inside a debugger to see at which _line_ it segfaults? (and then check the values of all involved variables)

Comment: About using gets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE *fptr;
```

You never opened a stream to a file, where `fptr` is pointing to.

Using:

```
fprintf(fptr, "\n%s\n", newPtr->name);
fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", newPtr->phoneNum);
```

invokes [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984) then.

Open a file with `fopen()` and check whether the returned value is a null pointer in which case we have an error routine:

```
FILE *fptr = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (!fptr)
{
    perror("fopen() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Furthermore you need to close a stream by `fclose(fptr);` when no longer needed.

---

To flush `stdin` with `fflush(stdin);` invokes under the most implementations also undefined behavior.

[Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/) with especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247021) explains it perfectly.

---

`gets()` should never be used. It is dangerous. Use `fgets()` instead.

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it. Is there any way to get rid of '\n' after using fgets for most cases ?

Comment: @chro1104 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221) - This is the best approach to remove the newline from the input.